# Look for specific character in string and place it at different positions after a defined separator in the same string

Tags: regex, string, r, split, pattern-matching

let's define the following string `s`:

```
s <- "$ A; B; C;"
```

I need to translate `s` into:

```
"$ A; $B; $C;"
```

the semicolon is the separator. However, $ is only one of 3 special characters which can appear in the string. The data frame `m` holds all 3 special characters:

```
m <- data.frame(sp = c("$", "%", "&"))
```

I first used `strsplit` to split the string using the semicolon as the separator

```
> strsplit(s, ";")
[[1]]
[1] "$ A" " B"  " C"
```

I think the next step would be to use grep or match to check if the first string contains any of the 3 special characters defined in data frame `m`. If so, maybe use gsub to insert the matched special character into the remaining sub strings. Then simple use paste with collapse = "" to merge the substrings together again. Does that make sense?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
getmeout = gsub("[$|%|& ]", "", unlist(strsplit(s, ";")))
whatspecial = unique(gsub("[^$|%|&]", "", s))
whatspecial
# [1] "$"
getmeout
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
paste0(whatspecial, getmeout, sep=";", collapse="")
# [1] "$A;$B;$C;"
```

Comment: Cool.  Note that escaping the `$&%` characters is unnecessary inside `[]`.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, that I did not know. Thanks. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sure.  You could also eliminate the `|`'s.  All the rules change inside `[]`.  It assumes that you are specifying "OR" and so there's no pipe necessary.  What you're actually doing there is looking for *four* characters: `$`, `&`, `%`, and `|`.  Example to demonstrate: `> grepl("[A|B]","$%&|")    TRUE`
`> grepl("[AB]","$%&|")     FALSE`

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, cool. I actually haven't done a whole lot with regex--usually just very basic cleanup--so thanks for the lessons!

Comment: thanks a lot for that solution. it looks the easiest to me and does its job! :-))

Comment: No problem.  One final note: The `0` in `paste0` refers to the fact that it doesn't insert a space in between (the default `sep=` character in `paste()`).  Thus there's no `sep` argument to `paste0`.  What your `sep=";"` is doing is having it paste a (length-one repeated using the usual rules) vector as another vector to be pasted.  Witness: `> paste(seq(3),seq(3),sep=";")
[1] "1;1" "2;2" "3;3"
> paste0(seq(3),seq(3),sep=";")
[1] "11;" "22;" "33;"
> paste0(seq(3),seq(3),";")
[1] "11;" "22;" "33;"`  The `sep=` part just gives the argument a name and is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
library(stringr)
separator <- '; '

# extract the first part
first.part <- str_split(s, separator)[[1]][1]
first.part
# [1] "$ A"

# try to identify your special character
special <- m$sp[str_detect(first.part, as.character(m$sp))]
special
# [1] $
# Levels: $ & %

# make sure you only matched one of them
stopifnot(length(special) == 1)

# search and replace
gsub(separator, paste(separator, special, sep=""), s)
# [1] "$ A; $B; $C;"
```

Let me know if I missed some of your assumptions.

Comment: I used methods from the library stringr recently. There are great methods in there to do jobs like that! Thanks to you as well for providing that solution!

Answer (score 1):

Back-referencing turns it into a one-liner:

```
s <- c( "$ A; B; C;", "& A; B; C;", "% A; B; C;" )
ms = c("$", "%", "&")

s <- gsub( paste0("([", paste(ms,collapse="") ,"]) ([A-Z]); ([A-Z]); ([A-Z]);") , "\\1 \\2; \\1 \\3; \\1 \\4" , s) 

> s
[1] "$ A; $ B; $ C" "& A; & B; & C" "% A; % B; % C"
```

You can then make the regular expression appropriately generic (match more than one space, more than one alphanumeric character, etc.) if you need to.

Comment: Thanks also to your solution. Similar anyway by also using gsub and the paste0 command! :) Great!